# ImportError: cannot import name 'Ontonotes' from 'allennlp.data.dataset_readers.dataset_utils'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, allennlp

I'm using python 3.7 and pytorch in google colab.
I installed

```
Pip install alennlp==2.4.0
pip install allennlp-models
```

In google colab, but when I run this code:
allennlp train experiments/oie_labeler_crf.json -s ~/Desktop/PHD/NLP/large-scale-oie/results/classic_train_crf --include-package large_scale_oie

I get this error:

```
File "/content/large-scale-oie/large_scale_oie/dataset_readers/oie_reader.py", line 12, in
from allennlp.data.dataset_readers.dataset_utils import Ontonotes, OntonotesSentence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Ontonotes' from 'allennlp.data.dataset_readers.dataset_utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/allennlp/data/dataset_readers/dataset_utils/init.py)
```

Please help me! What do I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Do you happen to have 2 versions of python installed?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using google colab. When I run python --version I get python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

You might be using an incompatible AllenNLP version. You can try to run:

```
pip install alennlp==0.9.0
```

I believe the error will be gone.